# Error del proceso del terminal al iniciarse: Path to shell executable "c:\Users\Ray\VSCodeWorkspaces\cpp\g++" does not exist. VSCode

Tags: c++, vscode, g++

Estoy programando en `c++` con Visual Studio Code, pero resulta que al iniciar me sale el mensaje:  Error del proceso del terminal al iniciarse: Path to shell executable "c:\Users\Ray\VSCodeWorkspaces\cpp\g++" does not exist. pero no se que es eso de `g++`

Comment: VSCode es simplemente un editor. Para poder compilar programas necesitas instalar un compilador. Lo que sucede aquí es que VSCode intenta localizar un compilador (de C++ en este caso) en la ruta que indicas y no lo encuentra.

Comment: entonces, necesito hacerlo en el IDE de Visual Studio 2022, no?

Comment: No realmente. Si, sería más cómodo hacerlo desde el mismo IDE. Pero también puedes compilarlo tu mismo desde el terminal o configurando correctamente el editor. También podrías utilizar CMake para esa tarea.

Comment: vale, usaré CMake